# How can I find out number of onto homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

We know that, for finite groups $G,G'$ if $\phi:G\to G'$ is a **onto**  homomorphism then, $|G'|$ divides $|G|$. But,this result will not help to predict if a homomorphism is onto(it will help to predict if a homomorphism is not onto). If I consider the homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_5$, as $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\infty$ we can't use that result. So how I can show there are any onto homomorphism or not?  and how can count total number of onto homomorphisms ?

Comment: I assume that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the cyclic group of order $5$.  Let $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ be a group homomorphism.  Show that $\varphi$ is completely determined by $\varphi(1)$.  When is $\varphi$ surjective?

Comment: You have your logic backward. While a homomorphism being onto implies much about the orders of the two groups, you can't ever use the orders to conclude that a homomorphism between them is onto (with the sole exception of $|G'|=1$). You can some times use orders to conclude that a homomorphism _isn't_ onto, but that's it.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, yeah we can't

Comment: Is there any result that filters onto homomorphism, and also tell number of such onto homomorphism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the key general facts:

- $\phi: \mathbb Z \to G$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$
- $\phi: H \to \mathbb Z_n$ is surjective iff the image of $\phi$ contains a generator of $Z_n$
- the generators of $Z_n$ are $u \bmod n$ for $\gcd(u,n)=1$